# my app not displaying text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app is simple: a user inputs text and the text is saved in the db and displayed. The problem is it displays blank. See in the picture for each dot there should be a text.

[image: dots instead of text]

**main angular controller:**

```
myApp.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
  var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });

  $scope.meetups = []

  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
  }
}]);
```

**html partial:**

```
<!--main.html-->
<body>
  <div id='main' ng-controller="loginController">
      <form ng-Submit="post()">
         <input required type="text" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPost.created_by" /> 
         <textarea required maxlength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPost.text"></textarea>
         <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chirp!" />
      </form>
      <div id="post-stream">
         <h4>Chirp Feed</h4>
         <div class='post' ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'created_at':true" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
             <p>{{post.created_by}} says {{post.text}} at {{post.created_at}}</p>
         </div>
         <div ng-controller="logoutController">
           <a ng-click='logout()' class="btn btn-default">Logout</a>
         </div>
          <div ng-controller="logoutController">
           <a ng-click='gotoregister()' class="btn btn-default">register</a>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="meetupsController">
     <h1>There are {{meetups.length}} meetups</h1>
     <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="meetup in meetups">
       {{meetup.name}}
     </li>
     </ul>
    <form ng-submit="createMeetup()">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Meetup name" ng-model="meetupName"></input>
       <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form> 
  </div>
</body>
```

**API code:**

```
var Meetup = require('./models/meetup');

module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var meetup = new Meetup(req.body);
  meetup.save(function (err, result) {
    res.json(result);
  });
}

module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Meetup.find({}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);

  });
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimum, verifiable example.  This is a lot of code for others to sift through.  Perhaps limit the post to include your form, data, and data-getter.

Comment: there i did my best can u help

Comment: Insted of {{meetup.name}}, try only {{meetup}} to see what you get...

Comment: You might want to put this line ($scope.meetups = [];) BEFORE your query?

Comment: i get a bunch of these {"_id":"58332ab8c59f7b03582f5b75","__v":0}

Comment: if that is your object definition it doesn't have a property for `name`, so that could be an issue.

Comment: where should i look for then please help

Comment: Your api is not returning the right data then, try printing in the api the data that you are sending...

Comment: i added the api code on my question can u help

Comment: do you use mongo? do the documents in the collection have a name property? if not there might be a problem in your savingroutine...